# Nested array vowels search

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope

I wrote 2 functions to search and count vowels among strings in nested arrays. The first function `searchVowels` does the actual searching and counts the vowels. The second function `countVowels` just declares the `vowels` (counter) variable, execute the first function and return the result. I had to do this because of the recursiveness of the first function which would have produced multiple declarations and returns of the vowels variable.

The problem is: even if I declare `vowels` with the `var` keyword (the scope should be the entire function), the inner `searchVowels` function would not see it. If I take the declaration out of the function and make `vowels` global, everything works fine. So my question is: why `searchVowels` don't see the `vowels` variable declared with `var` in the parent function?

```
var nestedArr = [
    "Elie",
    ["Matt", ["Tim"]],
    ["Colt", ["Whisky", ["Janey"], "Tom"]],
    "Lorien"
];


function searchVowels(arr) {
    //iterating through each element of the array (or nested arrays in the subsequent calls)
    for (let i of arr) {
        //checking if the element i of the array is a string or another array
        if (typeof i === 'string') {
            //looping through the elements of the string
            for(let j of i) {
                //checking if the current element of the string is a vocal or not
                if (j === 'a' || j === 'e' || j === 'i' || j === 'o' || j === 'u' || j === 'A' || j === 'E' || j === 'I' || j === 'O' || j === 'U') {
                    vowels++;
                } 
            }
        //if the element i of the parent array is another array, the function calls itself and repeats everything on the  nested array (recursive)
        } else searchVowels(i);
    }
}


function countVowels (arr) {
    var vowels = 0;
    searchVowels (arr);
    return vowels;
}

countVowels(nestedArr);
```

Comment: the scope of variables doesn't get "inherited" to called functions. You could _declare_ `searchVowels()` inside of `countVowels()`, then `vowels` would get inherited.

Comment: Well vowels is scoped to countvowels only so is not available in searchvowels

Answer (score 1):

> why searchVowels doesn't see the vowels variable declared with var in the parent function?

Because Javascript is a statically (lexically) scoped language and the parent-child relationship of functions is determined by how they are written, not how they're called (that would be a "dynamic" scoping).

To make things work as intended, you have to place the child function within the parent textually:

```
function countVowels (arr) {
    var vowels;

    function searchVowels(arr) {
        ...
    }
}
```

On a general note, try to avoid functions that modify external variables or otherwise change the outside world ("side effects"). It's much better to design your functions in a "pure" way, so that they only accept parameters and return values - just like mathematical functions. Example:

```
function countVowels(arr) {
    let count = 0;

    for (let item of arr) {

        if (Array.isArray(item))
            count += countVowels(item)
        else
            for (let char of item.toUpperCase()) {
                if ('AEIOU'.includes(char)) {
                    count++
                }
            }
    }

    return count
}
```

Here, each recursive copy of `countVowels` allocates its own local counter and returns it to the caller, which then takes care of adding it to its own counter and so on, until the uppermost level is reached.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is javascript *block scope.*

Here's an entirely alternative way to do this code:

```
/**
* All vowels in lowercase
*/
const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

/**
* Check if a character is a vowel
*/
function isVowel(character) {
  return !!vowels.find(vowel => character.toLowerCase() === vowel)
}

/**
* Search for vowels in nested arrays
* Return a string of all the vowels concatenated
*/
function searchVowels(arr) {
  let result = ""

  for (const i of arr) {
    if (typeof i === "string") {
      for (const j of i) {
        if (isVowel(j)) {
          result += j.toLowerCase()
        }
      }
    }
    else result += searchVowels(i)
  }

  return result
}

/**
* Count the number of vowels in nested arrays
*/
function countVowels(arr) {
  return searchVowels(arr).length
}

/***************************************
***************************************/

const nestedArr = [
  "Elie",
  ["Matt", ["Tim"]],
  ["Colt", ["Whisky", ["Janey"], "Tom"]],
  "Lorien"
]

console.log(searchVowels(nestedArr))
//> "eieaioiaeooie"

console.log(countVowels(nestedArr))
//> 13
```

Now each function has only one job -- search vowels searches and returns vowels, and then count vowels counts the results of that

Of course, in this new case, these two lines are equivalent:

1. `const numberOfVowels = countVowels(arr)`
2. `const numberOfVowels = searchVowels(arr).length`

The count vowels function is thus unnecessary and should be removed entirely

Answer (score 0):

[@georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) already explained the scoping problem. Just for fun I like to present an es6/regex alternative to count vowels.

```js
const nestedArr = [
    "Elie",
    ["Matt", ["Tim"]],
    ["Colt", ["Whisky", ["Janey"], "Tom"]],
    "Lorien"
];

console.log(countVowels(nestedArr));

function countVowels(nestedArr) {
  // note: only strings or arrays, otherwise empty string
  const flatten = value => {
    if (value.constructor === String) { return value; }
    return value.constructor === Array
     ? value.map( v => v.constructor === String ? v : flatten(v) ).join("")
     : "";
  };
  // note: included y (semivowel)
  return nestedArr
   .reduce( (s, v) => `${s}${flatten(v)}`, "")
   .match(/[aeiouy]/gi).length;
}
```

Comment: If you go down this route anyways, you could simply do `JSON.stringify(x).match(etc)` ;)

Comment: @georg Sure, *in this case* and even `nestedArr.join("").match(...)` would work ;). If the array contains object literals though, it would also count vowels in keys of those objects, or in the `join`-case the two o's per object literal `[object Object]`